# Set focus on element using jQuery coordinates/offset values

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery.fn.getCoord = function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    var x = elem.offset().left;
    var y = elem.offset().top;
    console.log('x: ' + x + ' y: ' + y);

    return {
        x,
        y
    };
```

};

The above function can be used to extend jQuery, it returns an object with the x and y coordinate of a given element, left and top value respectively.

Is there a way to set focus to an element based on these x, and y coordinates.

E.g

```
//Get button coordinates
let coords = $("#gridButton3").getCoord(); 

//Get height of current element in focus
let itemHeight = $("#gridButton").scrollHeight;

//Delta value representing some space in between elements
const delta = 30; 

//coords.x = 200
//coords.y = 50
//itemHeight  = 200
```

Given the above values in a n x n grid, lets say I want to set focus to a grid button just below gridButton3.

I would do the following :

```
let {focusX , focusY } = coords;

//Only changing y coordinate because we are navigating down, x coordinates doesn't change
focusY = focusY + itemHeight + delta;


//Here is the part I need some insight on

//scroll to new y location 
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: focusY 
}, 500)

//Now focus on element at coordinates (focusX,focusY)
```

I know how to set focus via element id or by some selector, I need to figure how to do it based on element at a given x,y .

Comment: You could use [`document.elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, perfect, looks to be compatible with most browsers. I think this should do the job. Thank you .

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan looks good so far,  you can post your comment as the accepted answer if you like.

Comment: Sure, I added it for you below. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an element from a point in the DOM you can use [`document.elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint)